# TextInputLayout hint is too high

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

Is there any way to add padding to hint, when you click eddittext?
I tried adding padding and margin in both edittext and TextInputLayout.

Currently:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            android:background="@color/color_line_transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Error">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_login"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: PRINTSCREEN]
[image: Printscreen On Click]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure if it works, but have you tried adding padding to the parent layout that's wrapping your TextInputLayout?

It looks like your TextInputLayout has the standard/default hint padding. So maybe you should go with trying to make the parent layout account for the large spacing between the hint of the TextInputLayout and the EditText views.

I wrote up a quick post on TextInputLayouts here, which may have some more tips that might help you out?: [w3bshark.com/blog/input-layouts](http://w3bshark.com/blog/input-layouts)

Comment: I did as you said. I added a RealtiveLayout and I have now inside only this elements. Every padding,margin i gave it to Relative Layout and now it works. Too bad you can't just add padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding in Edittext

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_layout_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:background="@color/color_line_transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Error">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_login"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the hint incorrectly, hint should be set on textinputlayout not edittext.